# Super not working on Model save

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
setattr(obj, 'tv_season_number', self.data['tv_season_number'])
super(obj, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: must be type, not TVSeriesMaster
```

I have also tried doing:

```
setattr(obj, 'tv_season_number', self.data['tv_season_number'])
obj.save()
```

And it gives me another error. How would I properly save this?

Comment: what is the full code?

Comment: what's you classes name? is it `TVSeriesMaster`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you named your class `obj`, your issue is that you haven't correctly named the class to overload. Try this:

```
super(TVSeriesMaster, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

An example of using super with classes in Django:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```